# Google Chrome has high CPU usage for my scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-applications

I have created a simple web page which has some effects based on two scripts. First is a rotating 360 panorama and the other is a scroll to top div. Both the scripts use SetInterval and run at 50 millisecond intervals. The page seems to run efficiently in IE and Firefox but causes problems in Chrome i.e. has high CPU usage in chrome nearly 48%!!!!

Please help.

The Code:

panorama.js

```
var pant=setInterval(function(){panorama()},70);
function panorama()
{
var panx=document.getElementById("uno").style.left;
panx=parseInt(panx);panx-=1;
if(panx==-1100)
{
panx=0;
}
panx=panx.toString();panx=panx+"px";
document.getElementById("uno").style.left=panx;
document.getElementById("dos").style.left=panx;
}
```

^ It works on 2 images.

scroller.js

```
window.onscroll = scrdisp;
function scrdisp()
{
var x=window.pageYOffset;
if(x>=350)
{
document.getElementById("scrolltop").style.display="block";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("scrolltop").style.display="none";
}
}
var t;
function scroll()
{
t=setInterval(function(){scr()},50);
}
function scr()
{
var h=window.pageYOffset;
if(h<=0)
{
clearInterval(t);
}
window.scrollTo(0,h-100);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check showing **scrolltop** element 1000 milliseconds is enough.

```
function scroll() {
    t=setInterval(function(){scr()},1000);
}
```

And you can increase perfomance like that:

```
var pant=setInterval(panorama,70);
var unoStyle = document.getElementById("uno").style;
var dosStyle = document.getElementById("dos").style;
function panorama() {
    var panx= unoStyle.left;
    panx=parseInt(panx);
    panx-=1;
    if(panx==-1100) {
        panx=0;
    }
    panx=panx+"px";
    unoStyle.left=panx;
    dosStyle.left=panx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only things that may cause instability are:

- naming functions in the global scope
- and especially using `scroll` as a function name which may be called elsewhere, but expecting `window.scroll`